# Why is this creating an infinite loop?

Tags: infinite-loop

Can someone explain why this is making an infinite loop? The hurcdata2 has about 30 straing values in it. I don't understand what the problem is.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
public class Hurricanes2
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    int i = 0;
    int hurricaneNumber = 0;
    String hurricanes = "";
    File fileName = new File("hurcdata2.txt");
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(fileName);
    while (inFile.hasNext())
    {
        hurricaneNumber++;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I don't know anything about Java but it seems pretty obvious you need some code within your loop to move inFile on the the next item. Something like `inFile.nextLine();` after `hurricaneNumber++;`

Answer (score 1):

In your `while` - loop you should call `inFile.nextLine()` to make it process each line in the file.

```
  while (inFile.hasNext()) {
     hurricaneNumber++;
     String line = inFile.nextLine();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comment by @ElectricLlama you need to advance your file pointer, to get the next token, otherwise the `hasNext()` will always be true. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352040/scanner-on-text-file-hasnext-is-infinite) and this [tutorial](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/50186-file-input-and-output/#axzz2FX6jIeiK) on File I/O in Java.