# Using while-loop to read from a file

Tags: java, loops, netbeans, while-loop, filereader

My question is: How do I use a while-loop to read inputs from a file ??

I wrote this code and I wonder how can I write it again in another way using a While-loop.

---

```
Scanner infile = new Scanner(new FileReader("while_loop_infile.in"));

    int sum;
    int average;
    int N1, N2, N3,N4,N5, N6, N7, N8, N9, N10;

    N1= infile.nextInt();
    N2= infile.nextInt();
    N3= infile.nextInt();
    N4= infile.nextInt();
    N5= infile.nextInt();
    N6= infile.nextInt();
    N7= infile.nextInt();
    N8= infile.nextInt();
    N9= infile.nextInt();
    N10= infile.nextInt();

    sum = N1 + N2 + N3 + N4 + N5 + N6 + N7 + N8 + N9 + N10;
    average = sum / 10;

    System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
    System.out.println("The average is " + average);

    infile.close();
```

-------------------- This is the input file ------------------------------

```
10
20
30
40
50
60
70
80
90
100
```

Comment: Duplicate question, [read next int from a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23676834/infinite-loop-on-scanner-hasnext-reading-from-a-file)

Comment: @gatech-kid That is not even remotely similar to this.

Answer (score 1):

With minimal modifications to just support the change you requested:

```
Scanner infile = new Scanner(new FileReader("while_loop_infile.in"));

int sum;
int average;
int N[10];
int i = 0;

while (i < 10) {
    N[i] = infile.nextInt();
    sum += N[i];
    i++;
}   

average = sum / 10; 

System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
System.out.println("The average is " + average);

infile.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Scanner` class has several methods for this. Most basic of which is `hasNext()`.

This method returns `true` if there is a token to be read.

```
while(myScanner.hasNext()){
    // Read next input.
}
```

EDIT: [Here is the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader());
double sum = 0.0;
int count = 0;
while (in.hasNext()) {
    sum += in.nextInt();
    count++;
}
System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
System.out.println("The average is " + sum/count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate question, [read numbers from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23676834/infinite-loop-on-scanner-hasnext-reading-from-a-file)

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader());  
double sum = 0.0;
int count = 0;
while(in.hasNext()) {
  if(in.hasNextInt()) {
    sum += in.nextInt();
  }
}
System.out.println("Average is " + sum/count);
```